# Bootstrap 3 - custom list group using a customized div having anchor tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in Bootstrap 3.

I am trying to create a customized group list in Bootstrap 3.

What I have done is -

```
<div class="list-group">

    <!-- 1 Ideal Item -->
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
            Header
        </h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">
            Item
        </p>
    </a>
    <!-- End - 1 Ideal Item -->

    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">
        Item selected and disabled
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Morbi leo risus
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Porta ac consectetur ac
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Vestibulum at eros
    </a>
</div>
```

And get a output like this -

[image: 1]

If I want to more customize any list with my own div having an a tag I get problem like this -

[image: 2]

And the code is-

```
<div class="list-group">

    <!-- 1 Ideal Item -->
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
        <div>
            <div>
                Anything
                <div>
                    <a href="mailto:joe@example.com?subject=feedback" "email me">email me</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                More thing
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <!-- End - 1 Ideal Item -->

    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">
        Item selected and disabled
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Morbi leo risus
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Porta ac consectetur ac
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Vestibulum at eros
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest `<a>` tags (it is illegal HTML).

Most browsers will actually restructure the DOM when they encounter this. Here is what Chrome is doing to your HTML when it renders it:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
    </a><div><a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
        </a><div><a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
            Anything
            </a><div><a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
                </a><a href="mailto:joe@example.com?subject=feedback" "email="" me"="">email me</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            More thing
        </div>
    </div>
```

Yuck! No wonder it looks messy. 
You can change the inner `<a>` to a `<span>` and use the `onclick` event to trigger the emailto. Note, you will need to style the `<span>` tag as a link manually (color, hover state etc) using CSS. **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/ncw1nhpj/)**

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
    <div>
        <div>
            Anything
            <div>
                <span onclick="window.location.href = 'mailto:joe@example.com?subject=feedback'">email me</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            More thing
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest `a` tags. When you do that, the browser will attempt to recover by essentially creating a new element outside the current anchor. Take a look at this example where the only change is that I've switched the inner `a` for a `p`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-group">

    <!-- 1 Ideal Item -->
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="baal">
        <div>
            <div>
                Anything
                <div>
                    <p href="mailto:joe@example.com?subject=feedback" "email me">email me</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                More thing
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <!-- End - 1 Ideal Item -->

    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">
        Item selected and disabled
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Morbi leo risus
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Porta ac consectetur ac
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        Vestibulum at eros
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The `mailto:...` doesn't fire in your example when clicked

Comment: And so it shouldn't. Like I said in the answer, you can't have an `a` inside another `a`. You could mimic an `a` with JavaScript though.

Comment: Yes, you can't have nested `<a>` tags, but you can invoke a click on an element nested within an `<a>` which is what the OP is trying to do.